QGIS buffer concave at the front and rounded at the back
I have point layer, where points are grouped into groups - every feature has point_id and group_id. I want to generate around group of point buffer (for example 1500 meters) where front of points group is concave and back rounded ... like in the picture.
convex_hull(buffer(collect($geometry,group_by:="group_id"), 1500 ))

Any good idea how to make the front concave? I assume that in the feature attributes I have to specify (for example true/false) which points are front and which are back in specific group
I'm using QGIS 3.28.15.

here is sample dataset,
link to sample dataset
in my real data set is thousands of points and hundreds of point groups, and the number of points in a one group can vary from 1 to 15 and front points can be also one-to-many

What do you call the front and the back of your groups? Are they alway 3 points layed out like you showed, or any number and randomly placed?

there can be any number of point at one group ... usually 1 to 15 points

Please add such information to your question. Something like that is essential to know to provide a good answer.

This expression makes a reasonable representation of the shape. It can be refined to produce a shape closer to the one you have drawn if needs be.
The expression assumes there is a boolean field called "front" to distinguish the points.
Bear in mind this was achieved using a Geometry Generator symbol layer. If you use Geometry by Expression processing tool, array_agg will need to be replaced by aggregate(@layer, 'array_agg', ...).
The output is a polygon geometry type.
-- the case statement is to render the final polygon only once*
case when @id = array_min(array_agg(@id, group_by:="group_id", filter:="front" is not null)) then

-- isolate the front points
with_variable('front_pnts', geometries_to_array(collect(@geometry, group_by:="group_id", filter:="front" = true)),

-- isolate the back point 
with_variable('back_pnt', geometries_to_array(collect(@geometry, group_by:="group_id", filter:="front" = false))[0],

-- make a line connecting the 2 front points
with_variable('connector', make_line(@front_pnts[0], @front_pnts[1]),

-- get the mid point between the 2 front points
with_variable('mid_point', line_interpolate_point(@connector, length(@connector) / 2),

-- make a line connecting the mid point and the back point
with_variable('connector2', make_line(@mid_point, @back_pnt),

-- make a new point at a specified distance along the line connecting the mid point and the back point (in this case 1/3 of the total length)
with_variable('new_point', line_interpolate_point(@connector2, length(@connector2) / 3), 
    
    -- `exterior_ring` is used in case the buffer distance is small enough to create a hole in the middle of the polygon
    exterior_ring(
        -- create the buffered shape
        buffer(
            -- construct a preliminary MultiLine shape between the front and back points (see diagram at end of answer for clarification)
            collect_geometries(
                make_line(@front_pnts[0], @back_pnt),
                make_line(@back_pnt, @front_pnts[1]),
            
                -- create a smoothed line between the two front points and the new point generated above
                smooth(
                    make_line(@front_pnts[0], @new_point, @front_pnts[1]), 
                    iterations:=3
                )
            ),
            
            -- this is the buffer distance. Here I use a relative distance (1/4 of the distance between the midpoint between the two 'front points' and the back point).
            -- an absolute distance can also be used of course.
            distance:=length(@connector2) / 4
        )
    )

))))))

-- close the case statement
end

* see this question and answer for explanation of the case statement.

Graphical explanation of the expression elements


what geometry type should be selected in gemetry generator module ... i prefefer polygon, because I want to fill diferent groups with different colors

Indeed, the output is a polygon, and should be selected. I will add it to my answer.

It would be nice to have some feedback from the downvoter to clarify why they think this is a poor answer.

This was downvoted?? 1 upvote from me- this is a great answer! What's going on here??

I my self downvoted this, because it is not working in my project, and I dont know what is wrong . maybe layer projection is not supporting this code in geometry generator ... I have 3857. and I dont see where is buffer dimensions in this code

@RiiPii, then may I suggest leaving a comment and asking for some help to get it working, rather than downvoting. A seemingly unnecessary downvote with no explanation does not help improve answers. And the buffer dimension is clearly indicated in the expression. Refer to the comment that begins -- this is the buffer distance.

Matt, sorry man but you changed your answer what was initially and it wasn't working form me ... I will check it again and if i get it working then I wil change my response

Matt, It is still not working in my project

it works only when 3 points are in group, the number is smaler or higher then it is not working and i dont understund how to change buffer dimensions - in your case it is divided with 4 - but i want to measure it in meters around point and it was indivcated in my code sample ... sorry

I answered based on the information in the question. I will take another look when I get time. Please add a link to some sample data. I don't want to have to guess what your data look like. For what it's worth, the only changes I made to the answer were to add some extra comments and a parameter name in the expression for extra clarification. The functionality remained exactly the same.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-p8T1nrCJGAEltfvkWRjjIq0rbX0yoT0/view?usp=drive_link
here is sample dataset, in my real data set is tousends of point and hundreds of point groups, and the number of points in a one group can vary from 1 to 15

and front points can be also one-to-many

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-qLKSNNaWnJKx4HXzUDkuXaKkPktDYib/view?usp=drive_link I'm sorry for the confusion, but I really assumed that you would understand without explaining that there can be many points in a group and many groups in a dataset ... in the picture in red, the current code is generated, in blue the correct group buffer should be added
